# How to change the the icon and font size of a tabbar lable in RNN V1

Tags: react-native-navigation

I[image]s there any way to change the icon and font size of a tabBar label?
i see the differece on android and ios, the icon on android is perfect, but in IOS is larger.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have all 3 density sizes for your images and everything should be ok. For example if you use `icon.png` as your image source, then make sure you also provide `icon@2x.png` and `icon@3x.png` so that the framework can correctly calculate the scaling on iOS. Good luck!